# How can I search/index multiple geo-location positions for a aggregated search?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using $geoNear to search for a business location based of a users location. However when I perform the search, Mongo only allows me to index 1 geo-location some businesses have multiple location, and I would like to be able to turn the location index to find the closest result.

This is what I currently have:

```
 location : {
        type: { type: String, default: "Point" },
        coordinates: { type: [Number], default: [115.8575,-31.953] },
    },
```

And this is what I would like to have:

```
 location : [{
            name: "Suburb 1",
        type: { type: String, default: "Point" },
        coordinates: { type: [Number], default: [115.8575,-31.953] },
    },
    {
            name: "Suburb 2",
        type: { type: String, default: "Point" },
        coordinates: { type: [Number], default: [115.8575,-31.953] },
    }],
```

Where the search would find the closest result. Is there an ideal way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/), you should consider redesigning your [data model](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/). `$geoNear` would return you the closest location (sorted), and it requires [geospatial-index(es)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/).

A suggestion would be to store a single document entry per business location.

You may also find [Tutorial: Geospatial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/) useful especially the examples.

Comment: Maybe a new store then simple for locations? Then it can have a reference to which business collection it is referencing? Would that be a better way of handling it?

Comment: Depending on the rest of information on the document, you can try embedding as much business metadata as possible. I.e. how often does business name/location changes?

Comment: It has a number of services which are refs, and a number of other items which are refs, all used for lookups